# Custom \hyphenation rule does not work on Overleaf

Tags: hyphenation

I want to break a long word to the next line in a 2-columns `acmart` template. The word is `Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word`. I have tried with `\hyphenation{Sample_Super-.Very-.Uber-.Long-.Word}` but it does not break the word.

Below is the sample on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{Sample_Super-.Very-.Uber-.Long-.Word}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

I also got an error notification on Overleaf that says **Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. Not a letter.** even though the document still compiles.
How do I set this rule? the same word can appear at many places so I'd like to set a global rule on this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dots from the `\hyphenation` entry?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the dot is part of the word.

Comment: Having dots in a "word" will almost certainly make it inappropriate for an ordinary `\hyphenation` pattern.  What you can do is create a macro equivalent with explicitly defined hyphenation points, then always enter it using the macro.  (This is not a limitation of Overleaf; it's built into TeX.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton could you help with the macro? I am new to macro... Basically, I have many words that contain `.` It's actually some variable names.

Comment: I can probably help, but will need to do some research first.  (I don't delve into the guts of TeX hyphenation primitives every day.  If someone else gets there first, that's okay with me.)

Comment: Have you tried "bracing" the dots, i.e. put them in braces `Super-{.}V`?

Comment: @henry It still does not break the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something a letter for consideration for hypehnation it needs to have a non zero lower-case code (it can lowercase to itself)

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\lccode`\_=`\_
\lccode`\.=`\.
\catcode`\_=12 % use  \sb for math subscripts
\hyphenation{Sample_Super-.Very-.Uber-.Long-.Word}
\showhyphens{Sample_Super-.Very-.Uber-.Long-.Word}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works :) but is there a general way? Like a macro as @barbara beeton comments? This is because I have many similar long words with `.` and `_` in them

Comment: that's just one document setting, it applies to all words, but I suspect that you do not want hyphenation at all and just allow breaking on `.` and `_` in which case look at the url package (but the question as asked is about `\hyphenation`

Comment: `url` works too, but in the final pdf, if I hover the mouse over such word, it will act as if it's an URL, also, in some viewer, it may have a blue box around it. Secondly, what I meant about a macro is something that would behave like `url` in terms of breaking, but not treat the words as an URL. I have many different long words like `Another_Super.Long.Word`, etc. So defining rule for each would be tedious and may be used as last resort.

Comment: @hydradon no I said the url package not the `\url` command, the url package just arranges line breaking it is hyperef that adds linking. the url package would allow you to define a custom command, or use `\path` which is like `\url` but hyperref does not activate it

Comment: the `\path` changes the font and add some extra spaces around the word. Could you show me how to override that? Or how to use a customized command from the `url` package?

Comment: @hydradon you should probably ask a new question. This question asks for a global setting for hyphenation to allow dots, and that's what this answer shows. It may be that you decide not to do that at all and have a non global solution which requires a command around each word and doesn't hyphenate at all, but that's really completely unrelated, even if for your real use case they are both possible approaches, ask a url package question with an example that does not work as you expect

Comment: Thank you, I have asked a separate question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524440/defining-a-customized-command-to-break-long-word-with-some-special-character