# Defining a customized command to break long word with some special character

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I want to break a long word to the next line in a 2-columns `acmart` template. The word is `Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word`. Below is the sample on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

I have attempted:

- using `\hyphenation{Sample_Super-.Very-.Uber-.Long-.Word}` but this is tedious because I have many different long words.
- The `\path` command, but this changes the font of the word and add some space around it.
- The `\url` command, which breaks line as I want without changing the font, however, it creates a hyperlink which sometimes shows a blue box around the word.
- I have read the [url](https://ctan.org/pkg/url?lang=en) package to create a customized command but have not figured out how.

How do I define a command with the `url` package? Or how do I achieve the same behaviour of `\path` without changing the font or adding the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're not actually looking to *hyphenate* a long word. Instead, you're simply looking to create a suitable line-break in that word. Is this interpretation correct?

I suggest you (a) load the `xurl` package, which allows for arbitrary line breaks in the argument of `\url`, and (b) use `\nolinkurl` instead of `\url`. This change is needed to make sure that the quasi-URL string isn't made into a hyperlink.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new

\title{test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt dolore magna aliqua. \nolinkurl{Sample_Super.Very.Uber.Long.Word} 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: Here's a screenshot of the left-hand column produced by this MWE. I've highlighted the output of the `\url` directive in yellow. Aside: I use MacTeX2019, and I compiled the test document with pdfLaTeX. I use `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3` and the `acmart 2020/01/11 v1.67` document class.

[image]

Comment: it will cause the S in `Super` to become like subscript, next to the `e` while the underscore `_` disappears. So it's like `Samplesuper.Very.Uber.Long.Word` I have tried to escape the underscore like `\_` but it does  not fix.

Comment: @hyradon — Did you load the `xurl` package and encase the very long word in a `\nolunkurl` directive?

Comment: I copy your code onto Overleaf. Could you check on your side?

Comment: @hydradon - Please see the addendum I just posted, including the screenshot.

Comment: it works on my local PC, but not Overleaf. I guess it's different engine, maybe. But thank you for the solution, I'll stick to my local PC